# Как почистить консоль?

Tags: c++, macos

При помощи какой команды я могу почистить консоль? Только не так, как работает команда **clear** в терминале, то есть я не хочу пропускать кучу расстояния, надо что очистилось что было до этого написано, и на его место вывелся другой текст? или так в априори нельзя?

```
int main() {
int x;
std::cout << "Введите число: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> x;
usefulcode(); <- команда которая чистит терминал;
std::cout << "Ваше число " << x << std::endl;
```

Comment: Ну тут многое от компилятора зависит, есть функция gotoxy (int x,int y) устанавливает курсор в позицию (x,y). Есть SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord) делает тоже самое.

Comment: Покажите конкретно, что должно очиститься и что должно остаться. Приведите пример

Comment: См. в сторону библиотеки `ncurses`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандарте С++ вообще нет такого понятия, как экран. Только поток вывода; более того, стандартными средствами даже не определить, сколько строк надо в терминал вывести, чтоб очистить.

Так что любое решение a priori платформозависимо и непереносимо.

Comment: Я бы все же сказал, что "любое примитивное решение". Все же зная ОС в которой работаем (а мы во время исполнения это можем узнать) можно много какой инфы о stdout вытащить.

Comment: @avp Можно. Но это и будет - платформозависимое решение (зная ОС, в которой работаем...)